# Free trial implementation for auto-renewable subscription

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, expo

I have react native app and i have implemented expo-in-app-purchases.I have setup all thing described in here https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb57be10e7.I have set up free trial of 1 week.My doubt here is that how this trial period actually working?

```
1) Is that working like we have to pay for first and the price will deducted only after one week?(Like Youtube premium).
2)Or we can access the feature for 1 week free and only after need to pay?
```

Is there anything to do in our code or only appstore setup?Can anyone tell me how the free trial actually working?What is the best thing to do?

Comment: When the user signs up for a free trial they go through the in-app purchase authorisation process and immediately get access to the subscription, but they are not billed. If they cancel the subscription before the free trial ends then at the end of the free trial period they are not charged and no longer have access to the subscription benefits. If they do not cancel before the end of the free trial then they are automatically billed for the subscription period.

Comment: @Paulw11 So anything to do in our end i mean in code?

Comment: @Khushi were you able to find out whether any coding(like backend or firebase) is required from developers side or not after implementing react native in app purchase?